# Octave: refer to output like %10 in Mathematica?

Tags: mathematica, octave

I want to reuse values. Is there a similar functionality as %10 of Mathematica in Octave?

> octave:18> 3/log (2)
>
> ans = 4.32808512266689
>
> octave:19> %         //how to output 4.328....
>
> octave:19> %%
>
> octave:19> %18

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need the last value calculated, the variable **ans** will do the job.

If you need it after several other calculations, you need to use the command **run_history** ***linenumber***:

```
octave:9> 3/log(2)
ans =  4.3281
octave:10> 42
ans =  42
octave:11> 37
ans =  37
octave:12> run_history 9
ans =  4.3281
```

Then that value is in the **ans** variable and you can use it in a calculation:

```
octave:13> 2 * ans
ans =  8.6562
```

**run_history** is a command, not a function, so it doesn't seem to be usable directly in a calculation (or else I'm getting the syntax wrong).  I'd love to hear about a more direct way if there is one.